# Select row where value is in column with multiple data separated comma

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-value

I have this scenario in my MySQL database:
[image]

I need select row where tag is from url parameter (GET)  with php-mysql query:

```
$tag = $_GET['tag'];
// example $tag = 1
// now I need select rows where in tags colums is value 1.
```

How can I obtain this query? I think that I need create an array... but I dont know how do. thanks in advance!

Comment: The best option is for you to normalize your database; otherwise [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: what do you mean for normalize my database? Can you do an example please?

Comment: I mean use a team_tags table, comprising a team_id and a tag_id column, with one row for each tag associated with your team - as per D Mac's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it this way - it will create trouble for you with every query until you fix it.

Instead, make a table of tags, and use a many-to-many relationship to associate teams with tags.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100),
    description varchar(255) );

CREATE TABLE teamtag (
    team_id int,
    tag_id int,
    CONSTRAINT 'team_fk' FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team ('id'),
    CONSTRAINT 'tag_fk' FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag ('id') );
```

Comment: And make `team_id` with `tag_id` as primary key.

Comment: Yes, exactly, @ElonThan. Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using `LIKE`/`FIND_IN_SET` but you definitely shouldn't.

Instead consider changing schema and adding dictionary table to keep all tags and join table to keep all connections between tags and items.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`Tags`, '$tag') > 0;
```